# PHP libxml2 entity invalid URL

Tags: php, libxml2

I'm trying to access an external entity in *libxml2*, but when the URL contains special characters like `<` and `whitespace` parsing fails. Here is the example url

```
<!ENTITY fe SYSTEM "http://127.0.0.1/echo.php?a=<?xml ?>">
```

can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: Can you modify that xml file?

Comment: I 'm not sure i understand.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you show us example of XML file with such an external entity and your PHP code? Or are you trying to create XML file? Most likely you need to convert special characters e.g. `& => &amp;` or double quotes `" => &quot;`.

Answer (score 0):

Before create xml file, you need to encode your urls. 
[urlencode doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Or please use `<![CDATA[your url here]]>`

[CDATA doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect)

Comment: I did think of that, but the web server (The receiving end) does not understand URL encoding.

Comment: CDATA didn't work, even tried to use parameter values, but putting in %param; still gives invalid URL error.

Comment: @Tios the receiving end is using the http protocol so it's obliged to understand URL encoding.